# Runtime error on large input C++

Tags: c++

My program seems to be working correct when n<=(10^4).
But for inputs like 10^5 ideone gives a runtime error plz help
ideone link [Code](http://ideone.com/Gll34O)

```
enter code here

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int t,i=0,n,j,sum;
    cin>>t;
    while(i<t)
    {
        cin>>n;
        cout<<n+1<<endl;
        sum=(n*(n+1))/2;
        cout<<sum<<endl;
        for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
        cout<<j<<" ";
        i++;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably because input/outut length (as well as memory, running time) etc. are restricted one Ideone (and any other online site). Install a local compiler on your computer. (And somehow you're missing many inputs)

Comment: @Stopdrake, think to optimize your program. Develop a better algorithm for your purpose.

Comment: @deviantfan this program is giving time limit exceeded on hackerearth where the valid inputs range upto 10^6.

Comment: @KishanKumar it already is in o(n) as each test case needs to be evaluated separately

Comment: @Stopdrake i think its o(n^2)

Comment: Indeed, it is O(n^2)  ... (not o(n^2), that's something different)

Answer (score 2):

Size of output must be `<=64KB` in **Ideone**. Considering even `sizeof(int)`=4 it will run for maximum of `n=16000`. This will give you a rough estimate of the output limit.